# Running maven Project motown.io

Tags: maven-2

I am studying a java project (motown.io) downloaded from github.I have opened the project and there is a lot of modules in the project and I have no idea about it.I am learning maven now but still the project seems bit out of reach.Can anyone who has worked in this project help me.Is there any easy way to get familiarized with it.I am not asking for codes ,I just want to know how to possibly run it.
Ps
My domain is .net but I have to learn this project

Answer (score 0):

If you're just curious about how to get the project running you could follow the steps in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/motown-io/motown/wiki/Getting-started) guide. The [wiki](https://github.com/motown-io/motown/wiki) itself has a lot more information on the project.

If you have any other questions about Motown it might be best to send them to the [Motown mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/motown-io) where the developers are active. We only stumbled upon this question by accident as we're not actively monitoring StackOverflow for Motown questions. Hope to see you on the mailing list!